# AttributeError in Scrapy web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I wrote a scrapy code to scrape a website but getting attribute error. Im new to web scraping so could you please guide me how can I fix this error.
here is error message: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'xpath'

here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class ShopSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'shop'
    allowed_domains = ['https://www.redbubble.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.redbubble.com/shop/shower-curtains/']

    def parse(self, response):

        products = response.xpath("//a[@class='styles__link--2sYi3']").get()
        for product in products:
            product_url = product.xpath(".//img[@class='styles__image--2CwxX styles__productImage--3ZNPD styles__rounded--1lyoH styles__fluid--3dxe-']/@src").get()
            title = name = product.xpath(".//div[@class='styles__box--206r9 styles__paddingRight-0--fzRHs']/div[@class='styles__textContainer--1xehi styles__disableLineHeight--3n9Fg styles__nowrap--2Vk3A']/span/text()").get()
            yield {
                'name'  :   title,
                'url'   :   product_url
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is obvious

You are trying to call `xpath` method from a string

Please change

```
products = response.xpath("//a[@class='styles__link--2sYi3']").get()
```

to

```
products = response.xpath("//a[@class='styles__link--2sYi3']")
```